# How to acknowledge system alerts automatically using KIF test framework?

Tags: ios, kif

I use [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) to test the UI for continuous integration. When the app is the first launch on a device (or **iOS Simulator**), the system will show some alert views for security. How can KIF automatically acknowledge system alerts to prevent test from failure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to use `[tester acknowledgeSystemAlert]`. It will click the last button in the system alert :)

For more information see [this](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/pull/510) github thread.

Comment: And for completion's sake, here's the Swift version even if it's obvious:

    self.viewTester.acknowledgeSystemAlert()

Comment: I dont have viewTester, what is it now instead of viewTester ??