# How to acknowledge system alerts on a device with KIF testing framework?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, kif

I found out how to acknowledge system alerts while on a simulator from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028960/how-to-acknowledge-system-alerts-automatically-using-kif-test-framework) post using this line of code:

```
self.viewTester.acknowledgeSystemAlert()
```

Unfortunately, the KIF code has #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR wrapped around it, so it won't work on a device. How can I get around permission alerts on a device during automated testing?

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and here the solution I found:

its right than this KIF function doesn't work on device, its only for simulators! so, You can have a UITest in the UITarget and just a single Test case in it that will add a UIMonitors like this:

```
// ask for all the permission from users then : 
   _ = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "") { alert -> Bool in
        let confirmLabels = ["Allow", "OK"]
        for (_, label) in confirmLabels.enumerated() {
            let allow = alert.buttons[label]
            if allow.exists {
                allow.tap()
                break
            }
        }

        return true
    } 
// do some UI interaction here like tapping on some view in app
```

**So you can call this UITest each time before running your UnitTests and that will prepare your app to have all the permissions.**

btw, if anyone has better solution please provide cause I wanna know, too ;)